# Getting date month in english format inside bash script

Tags: bash, date

In a bash script I have the following:

```
MES=$(date +"%b")
```

How can I get the month in english format?
Now if I echo $MES variable, I get abr. But I would like to get apr.

I'm trying to solve this without using if statement or switch. May be is an option...
I have tried `date -u` but is not working for me.

EDIT:
Finally I have put this line in the first line of script script:

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=en_us_8859_1 
# Here rest of the script
```

Now is working, but I can't accept my own answer as valid... I think because I haven't enough reputation in stackoverflow

Comment: Maybe, you need to change locale...

Comment: How can I do this inside the script ? LC_ALL=en_GB ?

Comment: Something like that... Check `locale -a` output for the exact string...

Comment: You may not want to change the locale for your entire script. You can limit the change to the single call of `date` with `MES=$(LANG=en_us_88591 date +"%b")`, for example.

Comment: Thank you chepner for the info.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

`MES=$(LANG=en_us_88591; date +"%b")`

to change the language just for this single call.