# If statement in Jenkinsfile, comparing strings not working

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to add a "validation" stage in Jenkinsfile based on the day of the week. If today is Sunday, validation is required, otherwise not.

the if statement is not working

here I am declaring the variable

```
DAY=sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +"%a"').trim()
```

and here is the stage

```
stage('validation') {
  steps {
    script {
      if ( DAY == "SUN" ) {
        echo "Validation is required, today is $DAY"
      }
      else {
        echo "No validation required, today is $DAY"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the output

```
No validation required, today is Sun
```

the value of the variable `Day` is correct, but the if statement doesnt work correctly

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the comparison is failing because the case of the word in DAY is different.
Try this

```
      if ( DAY == "Sun" ) {
        echo "Validation is required, today is $DAY"
      }
      else {
        echo "No validation required, today is $DAY"
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, to be *sure* of what you are comparing, is at least to transform the result in upercase. That way, your test will work unchanged.

And be sure to [force an English output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49771314/6309) for `date +"%a"`
(on my French setup, I get "`dim.`", not "`Sun`")

```
DAY=sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'LANG=en_us_88591 date +"%a"').trim().toUpperCase().replaceAll('.','')
```

That way, your Jenkinsfile will work on *any* workstation, no matter its [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)).