# How to format date string using shell script

Tags: shell

How to convert

Sat Apr 27 11:33:57 CST 2024 -> 2024/09/27

I use `date -d "Sat Apr 27 11:33:57 CST 2024"+"%Y%m%d"`, but not working

Comment: you missed out a space and two slashes: `date -d "Sat Apr 27 11:33:57 CST 2024" +"%Y/%m/%d"`

Comment: if you really want to convert to September, perhaps: `date -d "Sat Apr 27 11:33:57 CST 2024 + 5 months" +"%Y/%m/%d"`

Comment: I got error below
date: illegal option -- d
usage: date [-jnRu] [-I[date|hours|minutes|seconds]] [-f input_fmt]
            [-r filename|seconds] [-v[+|-]val[y|m|w|d|H|M|S]]
            [[[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.SS] | new_date] [+output_fmt]

Comment: then you are using a version of `date` that doesn't understand this extension. you can explicitly specify the path to GNU date or some other version that understand it, or you'll need to find a different tool

Answer (score 1):

Which one you want

`2024/04/27` :

```
LANG=en_us_88591 date -d "Sat Apr 27 11:33:57 CST 2024" "+%Y/%m/%d"

# 2024/04/27
```

or `2024/09/27` (`+5` months)?

```
date -d "$(LANG=en_us_88591 date -d @$(date -d "Sat Apr 27 11:33:57 CST 2024" +%s)) +5 months" "+%Y/%m/%d"

# 2024/09/27
```

#### Note

1. In my timezone, `date` will produce non-english output. If you want to force english output, prepend `LANG=en_us_88591` before `date`. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388671/getting-date-month-in-english-format-inside-bash-script)
2. The second one parsed timestamp from `+%s` then append epoch time to a `@`. Then set `+5` months via `date -d`.